# FakeItEasy Property doesnt get updated

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

For the first time, I'm using [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) to mock a complex data structure. When mocking an object and setting a property like this, the proprety doesnt get updated. It will always be false.

```
var @object = A.Fake<MyObject>();
@object.MyBooleanProperty= true;
```

Reading through documentation on FakeItEasy, an example shows that this can be done:

```
var @object= A.Fake<MyObject>();
A.CallToSet(() => @object.MyBooleanProperty).To(true);
```

The problem here is that the property is not marked as virtual, and this will throw an `FakeConfiguredException` with the message:

```
The current proxy generator can not intercept the specified method for the following reason:
    - Non virtual methods can not be intercepted.
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First option must work. If property not virtual, then it will execute "real" code. Unless your property's getter return value based on the other inner methods/properties which were overrided by FakeIteasy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the property isn't virtual, doing `@object.MyBooleanProperty= true` will just call the `MyObject` implementation, because FakeItEasy (and other mocking frameworks) can only intercept virtual members. So if the property is still false after setting it to true, it must be because of how it's implemented in `MyObject`. FakeItEasy isn't involved at all here.

As for this:

```
A.CallToSet(() => @object.MyBooleanProperty).To(true);
```

It just means "when `MyBooleanProperty` is set to true on `@object`. It doesn't do anything, because you didn't specify a behavior (`Invokes`, `Throws`, `CallsBaseMethod`…). To help detect this kind of problem, consider using the [FakeItEasy.Analyzer](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/analyzer/) (available [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FakeItEasy.Analyzer)), which will alert you of unused call specifications and other common errors.

Also, `A.CallToSet` is only used to configure the property *setter*. If you want to configure the getter, you should use `A.CallTo(() => @object.MyBooleanProperty)`. But anyway it can't work if the property is not virtual, as you have already noted.

Comment: Thanks for the details, much appreciated. I ended up with creating interfaces for my types and creating mock instances of interfaces instead with FakeItEasy. Please vote to close this post.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen, I wouldn't vote to close the question. It's a fine question. If I may be so bold, I'd suggest that if you're content with this answer, you upvote it (if you haven't already) and accept it.

Comment: Just to notice that some mocking frameworks can intercept non-virtual members. That "unconstrained" frameworks usually are commercials